# What is the best way to handle disconnect for Ionic 4/Firebase

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire, ionic4, angularfire5

I am running and developing an Ionic 4 application but I get plenty of console errors if the enable Disconnect on Chrome developer tools. What is the best way to handle this and stop the error generations?

**[Edit] - Some errors**

```
zone.js:3243 POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects%9e%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&VER=8&gsessionid=zS_Z186jbzIduyA8czPUNKQ3nDUeAStV&SID=6_aGSsvm--uKTRwIw6hLjQ&RID=45854&AID=18&zx=fotdumdzihh5&t=1 net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

zone.js:3243 POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects%89e%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&VER=8&gsessionid=zS_Z186jbzIduyA8czPUNKQ3nDUeAStV&SID=6_aGSsvm--uKTRwIw6hLjQ&RID=45854&AID=18&zx=6g8tdtpwagpv&t=2 net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

www.google.com/images/cleardot.gif?zx=k0fhnf17yuw:1 GET https://www.google.com/images/cleardot.gif?xxw net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

Comment: Can you please add some error logs which you are getting on Chrom ?

Comment: Posted some errors in the question

Comment: Those are the print statement from firebase plugin you can ignore as its based on your net connection.

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to use the network listener and show a toast if disconnected. The toast shows if no errors are in console. Somehow it does not if I simulate disconnect.

Comment: for network listener which plugin you are using?

Comment: Using Ionic Capacitor. Network.addListener('networkStatusChange').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with Firebase realtime database, where once the app goes offline there was a console log spam (caused by fb attempting to establish connection), where I had to use .goOffline() method provided by the SDK to prevent it.

With Firestore SDK there are similar methods:

- Disable: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore.html#disablenetwork
- Enable: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore.html#enablenetwork

Which you could call programmatically in the online/offline network listener callback. If you can share your particular implementation I could help you show how.

Comment: This led me to this post which solved the issue https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1510#issuecomment-375368755